# Python Apache Beam DoFn For Polling

Tags: python, apache-beam

I’m having trouble coming up with the best pattern to eagerly poll. By eagerly, I mean that elements should be consumed and yielded as soon as possible. There are a handful of experiments that I’ve tried and my latest attempt using the timer API seems quite promising, but is operating in a way that I find rather unintuitive. My solution was to create a sort of recursive timer callback - which I found one [example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.48.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/userstate_test.py#L797) of within the beam test code.

I have a few questions:

1. The below code runs fine with a single worker but with multiple workers there are duplicate values. It seems that the callback and snapshot of the state is provided to multiple workers and the number of duplications increases with the number of workers. Is this due to the values being provided to `timer.set`?
2. I’m using `TimeDomain.WATERMARK` here due to it simply not working when using `TimeDomain.WATERMARK`. The [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#state-and-timers) seem to suggest `REAL_TIME` would be the way to do this, however there seems to be no guarantee that a `REAL_TIME` callback will run. In this sample setting the timer to `REAL_TIME` will simply not ever fire the callback. Interestingly, if you call `timer.set` with any value less than the current `time.time()`, then the callback will run, however it seems to fire immediately regardless of the value (and in this sample will actually raise an [AssertionError](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/v2.48.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/runners/direct/transform_evaluator.py#L943)).

My concern with using something like a `time.sleep` within the `DoFn.process` method is that I'd like the runner to be doing something else if possible, and don't want a bunch of workers just sleeping repeatedly.

I'm curious if anyone has a better pattern for doing this and could clarify anything that I may be misunderstanding.

```py
import random
import threading

import apache_beam as beam
import apache_beam.coders as coders
import apache_beam.transforms.combiners as combiners
import apache_beam.transforms.userstate as userstate
import apache_beam.utils.timestamp as timestamp
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


class Log(beam.PTransform):
    """
    A pass-through transform that prints the element.
    """

    lock = threading.Lock()

    @classmethod
    def _log(cls, element, label):
        with cls.lock:
            # This just colors the print in terminal
            print('\033[1m\033[92m{}\033[0m : {!r}'.format(label, element))
        return element

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return pcoll | beam.Map(self._log, self.label)


class EagerProcess(beam.DoFn):

    BUFFER_STATE = userstate.BagStateSpec('buffer', coders.PickleCoder())
    POLL_TIMER = userstate.TimerSpec('timer', beam.TimeDomain.WATERMARK)

    def process(
            self,
            element,
            buffer=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE),
            timer=beam.DoFn.TimerParam(POLL_TIMER),
    ):
        _, item = element

        # Represents splitting out the element into individual pieces that
        # may finish in any order.
        for i in range(item):
            buffer.add(i)

        timer.set(timestamp.Timestamp.now() + timestamp.Duration(seconds=10))

    @userstate.on_timer(POLL_TIMER)
    def flush(
            self,
            buffer=beam.DoFn.StateParam(BUFFER_STATE),
            timer=beam.DoFn.TimerParam(POLL_TIMER),
    ):
        cache = buffer.read()
        buffer.clear()

        requeue = False
        for item in cache:
            # Represents some sort of check to see if the element piece
            # is "complete".
            if random.random() < 0.1:
                yield item
            else:
                buffer.add(item)
                requeue = True

        if requeue:
            timer.set(timestamp.Timestamp.now() + timestamp.Duration(seconds=10))

def main():
    # NOTE: When using a single worker, this pipeline will behave "as expected".
    #  Introducing multiple workers results in duplicate values in addition to the
    #  problems where the timer callback are fired immediately.
    options = PipelineOptions.from_dictionary({
        'direct_num_workers': 3,
        'direct_running_mode': 'multi_threading',
    })

    pipe = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
    (
        pipe
        | beam.Create([10])
        | 'Init' >> Log()
        | beam.Reify.Timestamp()
        | 'PairWithKey' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (hash(x), x))
        | beam.ParDo(EagerProcess())
        | 'Complete' >> Log()
        | beam.transforms.combiners.Count.Globally()
        | 'Count' >> Log()
    )
    result = pipe.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I do not know about the duplication, but I believe you see issues with the `REAL_TIME` timer, because you are starting a batch job. You need to replace the `beam.Create([])` with a streaming source, such as PubSub, then the `REAL_TIME` timer should work. Alternatively, if you want to test it locally, you should use [TestStream](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.testing.test_stream.html) and mock the advance of processing time of your incoming data.

Comment: Thanks @CaptainNabla for the response.

It does seem like generally the timer API is designed to work with a streaming pipeline. As far as `REAL_TIME` vs `WATERMARK`, I wanted to specify "run this callback in 10 seconds". My assumption was that using `REAL_TIME` uses the processing time (time.time()) and `WATERMARK` uses the event time to determine the "current time".

Comment: Yes you are correct, however, you have to be aware that the `WATERMARK` depends on the source of your incoming data. It does not need to trigger after 10 seconds on a real-time clock. Could be longer or shorter with `WATERMARK`.